# Truncate date to last monday or any day of the week in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given a `pandas.Series` storing timestamps such as :

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
0   2015-11-03
1   2015-11-17
2   2015-12-08
3   2015-12-22
4   2016-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to *truncate* the date so that i have only last monday of each timestamp

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
0   2015-11-02
1   2015-11-16
2   2015-12-07
3   2015-12-21
4   2016-01-04
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html#pandas.TimedeltaIndex) using the [`dt.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) attribute as `Monday` is day 0. Any day of week greater than this will result in timedeltas equivalent to the number of days to subtract:

```
In [49]:
s = s - pd.TimedeltaIndex(s.dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
s

Out[49]:
index
0   2015-11-02
1   2015-11-16
2   2015-12-07
3   2015-12-21
4   2016-01-04
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

E.g. for `2015-11-05`, `2015-11-04`, `2015-11-03`, `2015-11-02` the output of `pd.TimedeltaIndex(s.dt.dayofweek, unit='D')` is `3 days`, `2 days`, `1 days`, `0 days`, respectively.

Comment: Please be careful with typos, the original answer had `units='D'` instead of `unit='D'` which is silently ignored and pandas uses the default for unit which is microseconds. It is only a coincident with Guillaume's examples that substracting a few nanoseconds moves the timestamp to 23:59 and somehow still gives the right result.

Comment: @H.Brandsmeier thanks for pointing that out, that's a subtle typo error